# App ticker removed?

Tags: facebook

Facebook used to have an app ticker specially for games that should be on the right panel when in the application area. Has facebook removed it? I haven't really seen any news on it or discussions. As we're developing a facebook game is the support still there?

What about Achievements and Scores is that removed too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Achievements and Scores API still exist and are surfaced in news feed, aggregation units on timelines and in some cases in the main ticker.

The canvas-app-specific ticker was removed a few weeks ago and was [announced in January](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/641/); with the updated distribution in news feed  [mentioned in this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/05/games-update--expanding-distribution-for-scores-and-achievements/)